# Can Xcode skip unmodified projects to speed up compilation?

Tags: xcode, compilation

I'm working on a huge project, and compilation time is become a real pain.
I know in other languages there is a way to have a few projects with dependencies between them, and in case you change something only in one of the projects, the IDE will not re compile the projects that are not touched.

I would like to try taking this approach Xcode, but i noticed even if i use dependencies "Cocopods" , Xcode compiles them again and again every time, so i'm not sure this saved time at all.

Did any one try this approach?

Comment: Xcode shouldnt recompile them without modifications - you did something wrong.